# AngularJs function not found

Tags: angularjs

When I try to run this:

```
 (function() {
         'use strict';
        // 1. Module definieren
        angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('homeController',homeController);

        homeController.$inject = ['employeeFactory'];
        function homeController(employeeFactory) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.getEmployees = function() {
                employeeFactory.getEmployees()
                        .then(function(employee) {
                            console.log(employee);
                            vm.employees = employee.result;
                        });
            }; 

        }
    })();
```

I receive the following error in my console:

```
angular.js:13307 TypeError: employeeFactory.getEmployees is not a function
    at homeController.vm.getEmployees (homeController.js:11)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (angular.js:14157), <anonymous>:4:280)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15146)
    at callback (angular.js:24614)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16888)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16988)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:24619)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3394)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3382)
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Can you include your factory code while running this code ?

Comment: The issue is with `employeeFactory` and without the code, cannot certainly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the declaration of your factory employeeFactory.

The factory exists but it seems like getEmployees does not exists or you didn't declare it as a function.

If you want some help on this add the code where you declare that factory

Answer (score 1):

You define module in wrong manner,

```
 angular.module('myApp')
```

Replace it with

```
 angular.module('myApp',[])
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. The error you'd see then is Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.